# Confluence Logout using SSO

Tags: java, confluence

I have written my own seraph custom authenticator for confluence. I can login from my system and confluence is able to recognize that I am logged in. Everything is fine so far. The problem is when I try to logout. I tried to set the logout.url in the seraph-config.xml, however that simply redirects the user to my logout page, but doesnt logout the user from confluence. Then I tried to delete all cookies by overriding the logout method in my custom authenticator class however that doesnt seem to work either. The method is called, but the user is not logged out. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you saw this open [bug](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-4931) already.

A workaround from [JASIG](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+Confluence+with+JASIG+CAS+Client+for+Java+3.1):

To rely on the Single Sign Out functionality to sign off of Confluence we need to modify the logout link:

Copy $CONFLUENCE_INSTALL/WEB-INF/lib/confluence-x.x.x.jar to a temporary directory

`mkdir /tmp/confluence-jar && cp WEB-INF/lib/confluence-3.0.1.jar /tmp/confluence-jar`

Unpack the jar

`cd /tmp/confluence-jar && jar xvf confluence-3.0.1.jar`

Copy xwork.xml to $CONFLUENCE_INSTALL/WEB-INF/classes

```
cp xwork.xml $CONFLUENCE_INSTALL/WEB-INF/classes/ && cd $CONFLUENCE_INSTALL/WEB-INF/classes/
```

Edit $CONFLUENCE_INSTALL/WEB-INF/classes/xwork.xml, find the logout action and comment out the success result and replace it with this one:

`$CONFLUENCE_INSTALL/WEB-INF/classes/xwork.xml`

```
    <!-- <result name="success" type="velocity">/logout.vm</result> -->
    <!-- CAS:START - CAS Logout Redirect -->
                <result name="success" type="redirect"></result>
    <!-- CAS:END -->
```